# Proper way to bind the model to view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

Im newbie to mvc.I have a menusettings page where user can add menu according to his role.For that I want to create a view.How can I bind the model to view properly so that i can save the settings.My concern is inorder to access ienumerable item in the viewmodel,viewmodel should also be ienumerable.Here i cannot convert the viewmodel to ienumerable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**ModelClass is**

```
 public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuRole> MenuRoles { get; set; }
}
 public partial class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string NavigateUrl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuRole> MenuRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel Is**

```
 public class MenuRoleVM
{
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Menu> MenuList { get; set; }
}
```

**My controller is**

```
 public class MenuSettingsController : Controller
{              

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var _menuRoleVM = new MenuRoleVM
        {
            RoleList = new SelectList(_db.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "RoleName"),
            MenuList = _db.Menus
                    .Where(m => m.NavigateUrl != "#").ToList()
        };
        return View(_menuRoleVM);

    }        
}
```

Comment: You have passed the model correctly,  but the bindings depends on how you have used it in your view. You can have the view strongly typed, and use the properties inside a form so that they are received once you post it

Comment: A small example will be highly useful..My concern is inorder to access ienumerable item in the viewmodel,viewmodel should also be ienumerable.Here i cannot convert the viewmodel to ienumerable.

Comment: If you mean you want to display each `Menu` in property `MenuList`, then no, the view model does not have to be `IEnumerable` - you loop through each item in `MenuList` (which is `IEnumerable`)

Answer (score 0):

Below example will help. Here, I have the model ContactModel with properties - FirstName, LastName and Email.

```html
@model IEnumerable<CrazyContacts.Models.ContactModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input @Stephen.

I got the code running by the adding the view as below

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MenuList.Select((x, i) => new {Data=x,Index=i }))
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@(item.Index+1)</td>
                                    <td>@item.Data.MenuName</td>                                        

                                </tr>
                            }
```